# Is it possible to backup settings and apps for SGS with Samsung Kies?

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s, backup, samsung-kies

I want to backup my phone (Samsung Galaxy S) before having the carrier upgrade the Android version.  I don't want to root it because then the carrier won't upgrade it for me.

Is it possible to backup all the settings, SMSes, phone contacts (i.e. not those on google contacts), apps etc using Kies?

Comment: Even if you phone is rooted, you can always switch back to an state/fw without root so that your provider won't see the rooted phone.

Comment: @Flow: where can I see how to do that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Kies allows backups, but not the application settings, only limited content such as contacts, bookmarks, music, photo and videos. You can see the Kies tutorial on backup : Open Kies v2.0, "Help menu->Kies Tutorial->Backup & Restore mobile phone data" section for details and a movie. You can also try MyBackup free from market, which does not require root. Wish you luck!